# Question on a paper which talks about stacking several fully connected layers of 2 neural networks

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, lstm

So to preface, my knowledge on neural networks is very limited, and I've had a very difficult time trying to comprehend the details of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11227-021-04013-x).

My background is in maths, and I've created a continous wavelet CNN and the LSTM model, however I'm confused as to what I'm using in Equation 15 and 16. It looks to be just a sigmoid function, where I concatenate the 2 arrays (I assume I extend the $m_{i,j,t}$ array here), and then create a training function to estimate the weights and biases, but it feels like I'm skipping something important.

If it is the case that I'm simply using the sigmoid function, I plan on using [this section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Network_design) to create the NN and train as the paper recommends, however some clarification would be great. As I said, my knowledge on neural networks is pretty rudimentary, so I'm basically making educated guesses here.